# Register users using django oscar API

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm using Django oscar to build an eCommerce site. I have exposed every modules as an API using Oscar API. But I cant find an API for registering users by default in Oscar API.

Comment: That's because there isn't one :-). You probably need to use something like Django Rest Framework or create your own simple API.

Comment: You are wrong, there is a django-oscar-api.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like django-oscar-api currently does not provide an endpoint for registering users, only logging in pre-existing users: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/urls.py#L8

You will need to create a custom API endpoint that can register/create a User. You can add this endpoint by creating a new view, customizing the Oscar API and adding the endpoint to urls.py: https://django-oscar-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/customizing_oscarapi.html